# How to display HTML data from database

Tags: java, html, mysql

Using java/struts2.0, I am working on webpage where it fetches the data from MYSQL database and display it in the browser.

The database column contains the data in html format like

## Good Looking

wrapped in h1 tag. Now when i pull the data from DB and it shows exact same way as it is in DB having html tags around it.

I tried to store data encoding html tags as well but still no luck.

I am wondering if i have to do any kind of massage before i handover this data to JSP page.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `Now when i pull the data from DB and it shows exact same way as it is in DB having html tags around it.`

Could you ask a question? I can't understand this sentence.

Comment: @cbach, Sorry for the confusion. Lets say i have description column in database which contains text but in html format (wrapped inside html tags). Now when i pull that data from database and display in browser (using JSP), contents appears as a text which contains all html tags like <h1> or <p> or <li>. Somehow Browser is not rendering them into real html data. Hope it helps.

Comment: How are you sending the data to your jsp? And how do you display it in the jsp? Could you paste some code?